# How to model relation to different type of objects

Tags: php, mysql, oop, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am developing a software for creating and storing print layouts.

- A **layout** consists of a series of pages.
- Each **page** has one or more columns
- Within each **column** there will be one ore more elements
- Elements within a column are ordered: There is a fixed sequence of elements
- **Elements** may be of type "text" or "image" (for the sake of simplicity, in reality there are many more types)
- Different elements have different properties. Eg. images have a resource url, text has a font. See example code at end of posting.

My question is about modelling the relation between columns and elements.

## Idea #1: One table for all elements

This would be really straight forward. Add all properties as columns to a table and use N:N relation to model the relation between columns and elements.

Relation could look like this

<kbd>column_id</kbd><kbd>element_id</kbd><kbd>order</kbd>
<kbd>00000001</kbd><kbd>000000001</kbd><kbd>0009</kbd>
<kbd>00000001</kbd><kbd>000000002</kbd><kbd>0012</kbd>
<kbd>00000002</kbd><kbd>000000006</kbd><kbd>0003</kbd>

This seems not very appealing to me as the table to store elements would be polluted with empty entries, e.g. all `font` columns would be empty for image elements. It gets even worse if I consider all different erlement types I have (about 10).

Benefit: SQL queries are relatively simple:

```
select * from
  relation_table R inner join elements E
  on R.element_id = E.id
where R.column_id = FIXED_COLUMN_ID
```

## Idea #2: One table for each type of element

Modelling the elements would be quite simple, just create one column for all properties of class element and add the properties of the specific element type like image.

But how about modelling the relation column:element?

My first approach would be to try to add a column to the relation that specifies the type of element which would directly map to the related table:

<kbd>column_id</kbd><kbd>element_id</kbd><kbd>order</kbd><kbd>element_type</kbd>
<kbd>00000001</kbd><kbd>000000001</kbd><kbd>0012</kbd><kbd>text</kbd>
<kbd>00000001</kbd><kbd>000000002</kbd><kbd>0003</kbd><kbd>image</kbd>
<kbd>00000002</kbd><kbd>000000006</kbd><kbd>0005</kbd><kbd>image</kbd>

This certainly works but all sql queries to retrieve the elements for a specific column would get quite complicated.

## Questions

Is there an approach that combines the simplicity of sql queries from Idea #1 and the more accurate database modelling of Idea #2?

How do you approach this problem?

P.S.: Under other circumstances I would switch to a nosql based database but that's not possible :-(

```
<?php
// Sample code of element structure
class element {
    protected $id;
    protected $order;
    // more properties, getters and setters...
}

class image extends element {
    protected $image;
    // more properties, getters and setters...
}

class text extends element {
    protected $font;
    // more properties, getters and setters...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off starting with one table for elements and then adding join tables for extra info required for various element types.

It is usually a mistake to think about modeling data as real-world entities in db design but much better to take a step back and model based on the inner dependencies of the data.  These often coincide (and do so just often enough to make real-world entity focus look attractive) but when you run into cases where they don't it will cause you grief.

Here, you have issues regarding querying and ordering which are trivial to solve in a single table but will give you big headaches with many tables.

Comment: OK, after some thought I came to a similiar approach. One element table for referencing columns and storing common properties of all element types. And then add some extra tables for each element type which hold the additional properties. This would enable me to put the complexity of the sql queries into the classes defining the concrete element instances.

Answer (score 1):

Let me focus on the messy part:  "Different elements have different properties. Eg. images have a resource url, text has a font."  This begs, as you say, for lots of nullable columns or lots of different tables.  In either case, it is a mess.

A solution...  Put those "different elements" in a JSON collection of stuff.  Put it in a column and let the application decode it and make use of the stuff.

With that solution, the structure is still in the database, but the details are left for the application.  Seems like a fair tradeoff.

See other discussions of EAV.